# Is it possible for a round-trip through Python's mktime to fail with 'out of range'?

Tags: python, datetime, time

Given the following code:

```
value = time.mktime(datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).timetuple())
```

Is it possible for this to produce an OverflowError 'mktime argument out of range' and, if so, what range of timestamps would cause this?

Comment: Not sure why this got voted down; I realize it's a little specific, but I'm asking a real question about Python's behavior/limitations that isn't covered by the documentation.

Comment: +1 yes seems a valid question to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. I'm two hours ahead of UTC and on Windows. I get the error in the last two hours of the int32 range:

```
>>> def roundtrip(x):
...     return time.mktime(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x).timetuple())
...
>>> roundtrip(2**31-1-7200)
2147476447.0
>>> roundtrip(2**31-7200)
OverflowError: mktime argument out of range
>>> roundtrip(2**31-1)
OverflowError: mktime argument out of range
>>> roundtrip(2**31)
ValueError: timestamp out of range for platform time_t
```

Answer (score 1):

NB: the way you've asked it, I guess there's no possible timestamp that will trigger the specific exception you're looking for, because `datetime.fromtimestamp` will raise a `ValueError` instead, as it is bound (probably) by the same limits.

Now, the ranges for `mktime` are platform dependent, so I cannot give you a definite answer. In my Linux 32 bit computer, the boundaries are within signed 32bit integer, so a tuple that translates to less than -2147483648 (ie. before `(1901, 12, 13, 19, 44, 16)`) or past 2147483647, or `(2038, 1, 19, 3, 14, 7)`, will trigger that exception... but again, for you, `datetime.fromtimestamp` will catch it earlier.